# Ncurses function to create a Window

Tags: c, ncurses

New to nCurses here so forgive me the simplicity, but how can I use create a Window trough a function and return this to Main? Below is kind of the idea I am trying to create.

Any tips in this case? Not sure if this a logical way to go.

```
char createwindow();

int main()
{
     initscr();

     createwindow(border);

     wgetch(border);
     endwin();
     return 0;  
}

char createwindow(char _temp)
{   
    WINDOW *temp=newwin(30,30,30,30);
    box(temp,0,0);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a pointer to the new window in the same way you can return any other value:
Make sure your return value matches return type of your function.

If you want to return a `WINDOW*` change your function as follows:

```c
WINDOW *createwindow(char _temp)
{
    WINDOW *temp=newwin(30,30,30,30);
    box(temp,0,0);
    return temp;
}
```

Then you can store the result of that function in the caller function:

```c
WINDOW *newwindow = createwindow(border);
```

Comment: Also, `char _temp` isn't doing anything here, except receiving the nonexistent value `border` from `main()` (and then discarding it).

Comment: I know. I just did not want to modify more than required. If the code shown is only a MCVE, the paramter might well be used in the real code.

Comment: Yeah that was more directed at the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with your tips and did it as follows:

```
WINDOW* createwindow(); //Prototype function

main() 
{
   WINDOW *border = createwindow();
}

WINDOW* createwindow() 
{   
    int ymax,xmax;
    getmaxyx(stdscr,ymax,xmax);
    WINDOW *temp=newwin(ymax-1,xmax-1,1,1);
    box(temp,0,0);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer to your question, then you should mark it as answered.